# Jenkins error: svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL............ svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times

Tags: python, git, svn, jenkins

I am tying to run python code given below:

```
import re
import subprocess
import os

repoBaseURL = 'https://www.collabnet.xxx.com/xxxx/xxx'
svnPath = 'C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\svn.exe'


REPO_SRC = ('trunk')

REL_NUM = ('9999')

if not REL_NUM:
    raise Exception('REL_NUM should be filled in.' )

p = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\svn.exe', 'list', repoBaseURL  + 'branches'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
if not out:
    print err
    exit(-1)
```

> The script is working fine standalone but while running it using
>   jenkins I am getting error:

***svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL.............................................................. 
svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times.

Authenticaion Failed***

Any suggestions ?

Thanks For your help

Answer (score 0):

If your script is running in standalone, then you have to check your Jenkins configuration, generally Jenkins will use Jenkins stored credentials to connect to SVN repository, if you are not providing any credentials explicitly.

Hope you have already installed SVN plugin in Jenkins, open the Jenkins job configuration, and there you have to provide your credentials to connect SVN, you can test from there it self. If connection is success the same you can try to implement with your scripting.

Comment: I have installed Credentials, SVN plugins. 
But the jenkins job is accessing the repository to Build level i.e. my python code is trying to access it. My saved global credentials and my domain specific credentials are not getting passed in this python script.

The code is running fine standalone but with jenkins job credentials are not passing.